# How can I add multiple components to a vertically scrollable panel with different sizes

Tags: java, swing

So I have been trying to come up with a good layout manager that will enable me to put multiple components in a scrollable panel with different sizes. The only one I found was gridlayout, but it forces the same size.

here is the current code I have:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create and set up a frame window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Define the panel to hold the components
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 800));

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Button " + i);
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 100 + (i * 10)));
            panel.add(button);
        }



        // Add the panel and set the window to be visible
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I also do know about GridBagLayout, but I do want a layout that wouldn't require me to enter the numbers manually.

Comment: You can use a `BoxLayout`. See the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples of all the layout managers.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` might be another option

Comment: @MadProgrammer but I tried, and couldn't do it. If you read the last line of my question, you will understand.

Comment: @albertos No offence, `GridBagLayout` is by far the most flexible option, but it might to a little more understanding before the reason we'd recommend it would become apprarent

Answer (score 1):

> I also do know about GridBagLayout, but I do want a layout that wouldn't require me to enter the numbers manually.

You can specify:

```
 constraint.gridWidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
```

and each component will be placed on a new row.

Or you can use a `BoxLayout`, as I suggested in my comment, and not worry about constraints.

Read the tutorial. The constraints for the `GridBagLayout` are explained in more detail.

Comment: but the GridBagLayout wouldn't work with scrolling then :/

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: @albertos *but the GridBagLayout wouldn't work with scrolling then* - you have to add the panel to the viewport of a JScrollPane and add the scroll pane to the frame. Again, the tutorial covers all the Swing basics if you want examples.

Comment: @albertos glad it helpe. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.